# Why the command in singularity container can not be run?

Tags: singularity-container

In my project, i use singularity to build a mpi.sif.

I have a openMPI in my host file  system. I do not want to install mpi in the container.

so i try to copy the mpi files to container.

Some content of the define mpi.def is like :

```
[stack@node01 pitzDaily]$ cat mpi.def 
Bootstrap: docker
From: centos:7

%help
This recipe provides an OpenFOAM-7 environment installed
with GCC and OpenMPI-4.

%labels
Author stack

%files from stage_name

/share/apps/openmpi/intel/3.1.2/ /opt/openmpi-3.1.2

%post

### Install prerequisites
```

I can get the mpi.sif successfully after the building.

But i ran mpicc in container, it is wrong:

```
Singularity> mpicc
 mpicc: error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No 
 such file or directory
Singularity> echo $PATH
 /opt/openmpi-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Singularity> cd /opt/openmpi-3.1.2/bin/
Singularity> ls
aggregate_profile.pl  mpiCC    mpif77   mpirun      ompi_info    ompi-top      orte-clean  
orte-info  orte-server  oshcc   oshfort profile2mat.pl  shmemcc   shmemfort
mpic++            mpicxx   mpif90   ompi-clean  ompi-ps  opal_wrapper  orted       orte-ps    
orte-top       oshCC   oshmem_info  prun        shmemCC   shmemrun
mpicc             mpiexec  mpifort  ompi-dvm    ompi-server  ortecc        orte-dvm    orterun    
oshc++     oshcxx  oshrun   shmemc++    shmemcxx
```

In fact, i have mpi files in container, but it is wrong:

```
Singularity> ./mpicc
./mpicc: error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so.1: cannot open shared object file: 
 No such file or directory


Singularity>ldd ./mpicc
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1d79f000)
libopen-pal.so.40 => /opt/openmpi-3.1.2/lib/libopen-pal.so.40 (0x00007f0a6cade000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0a6c7dc000)
libnuma.so.1 => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0a6c5d4000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0a6c3d1000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0a6c1bb000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0a6bfa5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0a6bd89000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0a6b9bb000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0a6b7b7000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0a6ce13000)
libnuma.so.1 => not found
libimf.so => not found
libsvml.so => not found
libirng.so => not found
libintlc.so.5 => not found
```

Who can give me a help?

Comment: You can run ldd on ./mpicc to determine which shared objects are missing. Then you can install them in the container with the system package manager.

Comment: my host os is redhat, but my container is centos. maybe it can not copy the mpi files directory,  Thank you